# How to delete Spring Boot logging files automatically?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, logback, slf4j

I use the following logging config in my Spring Boot apps and save logs in that log file. But it creates many files (e.g. `application.log.2023-02-26.0.gz`) and after a certain period of time, I need to delete old log files based on size or creation date.

```
logging:
  pattern:
    console: "%d %-5level %logger : %msg%n"
    file: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
  level:
    org.springframework.web: error
    org.hibernate: error
    com.demo.app: debug
  file:
    name: './logs/application.log'
```

So, how can I remove old log files automatically?

Comment: Note: read the lower answers to the duplicate question.  `file.max-history: 50` will be part of your solution.  50 is an arbitrary number

Comment: @CLOSERS Why did you close without reading the question? I had already read that page but not solved my problem. I hope you read at least comments.

Comment: @DwB It is for rolling, but I want to remove old log files completely.

Comment: As noted in my comment, file.max-history defines the maximum number of files that will stick around.

Comment: @DwB `logging.file.max-size` seems to work, but `logging.file.max-history` is not and it continues to create a new log even if it exceed the given max number. Any idea?